# How do I attach a MSSQL 2000 database with only an MDF file

Tags: sql-server, database, recovery

I have an old server with a defunct evaluation version of SQL 2000 on it (from 2006), and two databases which were sitting on it.

For some unknown reason, the LDF log files are missing. Presumed deleted.

I have the mdf files (and in one case an ndf file too) for the databases which used to exist on that server, and I am trying to get them up and running on another SQL 2000 box I have sitting around.

`sp_attach_db` complains that the logfile is missing, and will not attach the database. Attempts to fool it by using a logfile from a database with the same name failed miserably. `sp_attach_single_file_db` will not work either. The mdf files have obviously not been cleanly detached.

How do I get the databases attached and readable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this answer, which worked with my SQL 2000 machines:

**How to attach a database with a non-cleanly detached MDF file.**

**Step 1:** Make a new database with same name, and which uses the same files as the old one on the new server.

**Step 2:** Stop SQL server, and move your mdf files (and any ndf files you have) over the top of the new ones you just created. Delete any log files.

**Step 3:** Start SQL and run this to put the DB in emergency mode.

```
sp_configure 'allow updates', 1
go
reconfigure with override
GO
update sysdatabases set status = 32768 where name = 'TestDB'
go
sp_configure 'allow updates', 0
go
reconfigure with override
GO
```

**Step 4:** Restart SQL server and observe that the DB is successfully in emergency mode.

**Step 5:** Run this undocumented dbcc option to rebuild the log file (in the correct place)

```
DBCC REBUILD_LOG(TestDB,'D:\SQL_Log\TestDB_Log.LDF')
```

**Step 6:** You might need to reset the status. Even if you don't, it won't do any harm to do so.

```
exec sp_resetstatus TestDB
```

**Step 7:** Stop and start SQL to see your newly restored database.

Comment: I also had to set it back to multi user mode afterwards as for some reason it ended up in restricted user mode: ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET MULTI_USER

Answer (score 1):

In Enterprise Manager, right-click the server and choose Attach Database. Select the MDF file and click Ok. It will then ask you if you want to create a new log file or not. Say Yes.

Comment: Sadly, it still complains that "the physical file name blah.ldf may be incorrect." when I try this with a badly detached mdf.